# codeigniter- Call to undefined function getNombre()

Tags: php, codeigniter

can someone help me with this?. It gives me following Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getNombre() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\views\vista.php on line 6

this is my controller(`c1.php`)

```
<?php

class c1 extends CI_Controller{

    function _construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('mihelper');
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('headers');
        $this->load->view('vista');
    }

}

?>
```

this is in my helper(`mihelper_helper.php`)

```
<?php

function getNombre(){
    return "<h1>Arturo</h1>";
}
?>
```

this is my view(`vista.php`)

```
<body>

    <h1>Llamado desde controlador</h1>

    <?php getNombre() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a underscore in the controller's construct function. So the helper is not able to load and the function is undefined. Updated code as below,

```
<?php

class c1 extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('mihelper');
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('headers');
        $this->load->view('vista');
    }

}

?>
```